# Finding the center of the viewpoint in DynamicGeoGraphics

Tags: dynamic, options, geographics

My goal here is to be able to display the coordinates of the center of a `DynamicGeoGraphic` which updates as the map is dragged (without right clicking on the map to get coordinates).

One method I came up with to do this was to read the `GeoRange` of the map, then take the average of the latitudes and longitudes in the `GeoRange`, but the `GeoRange` doesn't update dynamically as the map is dragged:

```
Column[
{map = DynamicGeoGraphics[GeoPosition[{40.097191, -88.245990}]],
Dynamic[Options[map, GeoRange]]}]
```

I've provided a specific `GeoPosition` here just for the sake of clarity. I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to access information about the map directly than what I've done here?
2. Why won't the `GeoRange` change as the map is moved?

Any other ideas for how to accomplish this are also welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Final code depends of your exact needs but here is something to start with:

```
Insert[
  ToBoxes@DynamicGeoGraphics[],
  Initialization :> (CreatePalette[
     DynamicModule[{}, 
      Panel@Column[{EvaluationCell[], 
         Dynamic[Column@{Typeset`geoRange$$, Typeset`geoZoom$$, 
            Typeset`geoProjection$$}]}], InheritScope -> True]]),
  {1, 1, -1}
  ] // RawBoxes
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is closest to what I was hoping to find, but I'm having trouble understanding what's actually going on with your code. I've not seen a context used in this way before. Could you expand a bit on why/how this works?

Comment: @TexasRed I will later :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a comment.

The following gives dynamically the XYZ coordinates asked to the tiles server OpenStreetMap (not Wolfram Tile Server). It updates when you release the mouse button in the map.

A particularly interesting thing is that the option `GeoServer` of `GeoGraphics` works also with `DynamicGeoGraphics`.

```
Dynamic[{x, y, z}]
DynamicGeoGraphics[
 Entity["City", {"Paris", "IleDeFrance", "France"}], 
 GeoServer -> 
  StringTemplate[
   "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/<*z=#1*>/<*x=#2*>/<*y=#3*>.png"]]
```

**Edit**
This gives the coordinate of the last tile asked to the server, which is probably  not the center of the map.
**End Edit**

Comment: Very interesting. I was hoping to be able to update the value while the map was dragged, not just when it was released, but this is quite clever. I take it that the reason this works has more to do with OpenStreetMap than Mathematica?